# Indeterminate ProgressBar is frozen when added to list footer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add a spinning progressbar to a footerview in a listview to show that more things are loading. the problem is i have this weird bug where the progressview shows up but is just frozen, and not animating. I gets even weirder though because this list is in a tab view and if i switch tabs forward and back a few times is starts animating. so something isnt getting refreshed or enabled or something

here is the footer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code to add it to the bottom

```
entryList = (ListView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.recent_list_view);
adapter = new EntryListAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Entry>());
entryList.setAdapter(adapter);
footerLoading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_footer,null);
entryList.addFooterView(footerLoading,null,false);
```

and here is what it looks like. the progressbar is there but frozen. 
Any suggestions?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have tried adding some styles ?

Comment: No. what do you think would that change? ill go try it though

Comment: Like adding attribute `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"` to ProgressBar.

Comment: ok i just added it. it still doesnt animate

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:indeterminate="true"`.